# Recreating a node tree removing certain, uneeded elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, tree, nodes

I'm working with a WYSIWYG editor, and trying to clean up what I'm given back from it. Here are two examples of transformations

```
<div>                       <div>
  <p>                         <blockquote>
    <blockquote>                <span>
      <p>                         <b>
        <span>      --->            <i>
          <b>       --->              <u>
            <u>               <p>
              <i>               Text
    <p>                       <p>
      Text                      Text
    Text
```

OR

```
<div>                       <div>
  <p>                         <blockquote>
    <blockquote>                <h1>
      <h1>                        Text
        Text                      <ul>
        <ul>                    Text
      Text          --->      <p>
    Text            --->        Text
    <h3>                      <h3>
  <p>                         <p>
    Text                        Text
    <b>                         <b>
      <i>                         <i>
  <h2>                        <h2>
```

So, what's happening here:

`<p>`, `<blockquote>`, and `<h*>` are not allowed inside of each other.
`<p>`, `<blockquote>`, `<h*>`, `<ul>`, and `<ol>` are allowed by be direct descendants of `<div>` only. Anything else should be inside of one of these.

So what I need to do is effectively walk the tree, and place them in the right hierarchy.

As you can see from the first example, the `<blockquote>` gets pulled out of the `<p>`, the `<p>` gets pulled out of the `<p>`, and then, a new `<p>` is created to hold the remaining `Text`, and the first `<p>` is deleted (At least that's how I see it, it could also be the last `Text` is put inside the unused `<p>`).

The second one, the `<blockquote>` is pulled out of the `<p>`, The remaining `Text` is placed inside a new `<p>`, or the unused `<p>`, however you see it, the `<h3>` is puled out of the `<p>`, and everything else is fine, so it's left alone.

I'm really having trouble getting the logic right on this to where it will correctly place elements, and create new ones. Keeping in mind this is a pretty shallow example, but I might need to say pull something out a few levels, or remove a node that isn't doing anything, (`<p>` inside of a `<blockquote>`).

This is the best pseudo I've come up with, but it still has problems.

```
if not p and not BQ and not h*
    create p
    fragment.appendChild(node)
else if (p && hasParent(p || BQ || H*)) or 
        (h* && hasParent(p || h*)) or
        (BQ && hasParent(p || h*)
            fragment.appendChild(node)
else
    fragment.lastChild.appendChild(node)
```

It doesn't work though, as the first `if` would constantly be creating `<p>`'s on child nodes, like a `Text` inside of a `<blockquote>`. And a few other errors, but what is important is that it's flawed logic.

Can anybody help me get this logic correct? Pseudo code is obviously fine, but I'm just really having trouble wrapping my head around this hierarchy. It's occurred to me that a recursive function might be useful, but I haven't figured out even something half-way decent on that.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. Basically, what happens is if I find a node that doesn't comply to the standards, it, and everything after it are moved to below the parent. This process is just repeated until everything is valid.

The code for `isValidTree` is not shown. All that does is validate a subtree, based on my rules of what I'm looking for. It returns a `node` if the tree is not valid, telling me where to start the removal, or true is everything is okay inside of that tree.

```
function rebuildTree(doc, node){
    // Keep track the original tree
    var original = node.parentNode;

    // As long as node is valid
    while(node){
        // Remember who the next sibling is, that way we can keep inserting before it
        var sibling = node.nextSibling;

        // Check if node is valid
        var badNode = isValidTree(node);

        // If we didn't get true back, then we need to move badNode, and all next-siblings to after the parent
        if(badNode !== true){
            // Get the next sibling, so we don't lose track of it
            var nextNode = badNode.nextSibling;

            // While we have a badNode
            while(badNode){
                // If we have a text node
                if(badNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "#text"){
                    // Create a paragraph
                    var p = doc.createElement("p");
                    // And place the textNode into the paragraph
                    p.appendChild(badNode);

                    // Then insert the node before the sibling
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(p, sibling);

                    // And remove the original
                    badNode.parentNode.removeChild(badNode);
                }
                // Otherwise, we can just insert the badNode before the sibling
                else{
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(badNode, sibling);
                }

                // Then assign badNode to be the nextNode
                badNode = nextNode;
                // And get the nextNode (If it's not null yet)
                if(nextNode){
                    nextNode = badNode.nextSibling;
                }
            }
        }
        // Now go to the next sibling of node, which at this point may be one of it's once-was children
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    // Return the node's parent (i.e. the entire tree)
    return original;
}
```